# Difference between running and executing a test

Tags: manual-testing

Is there any difference between running and executing a test? If so, what is it?

Comment: same thing, depends on who likes what word or company test jargon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the same thing.

You've probably noticed there are multiple ways to describe the same thing. There is no standard terminology in testing so if you are unclear about the word being used, it's always best to ask.